# Connect domain name with Linux VPS server ip using nginx

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, proxy, webserver

I have a VPS Linux (Ubuntu) server and I would like to connect a domain name with my server IP through nginx, but nginx does not work. I have checked the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl reload nginx

nginx.service is not active, cannot reload

$ sudo service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-15 18:53:40 CEST; 11s ago

$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown "connection_upgrade" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

In relation to run an app on my own domain, I have a nginx configuration file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/shiny

server {

        server_name my_domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
                proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_read_timeout 20d;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }

}
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: its a problem with your nginx config file, as the logs says there is a unkown variable `connection_upgrade` used there.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the [tour], if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/shiny` with this :

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

and then run `nginx -t` to test the configuration file, the output should be like this if everything was alright :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

then run `nginx -s reload` so the nginx will update the configurations on the fly.

and don't forget to delete that `proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;` and add a  `listen 4444` at the end of server block to specify the listen port.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your solution, but in my case it does not work.

Comment: you should delete `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` and keep `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
`